# Pass value to lightning-input tag in LWC

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

Does anyone know how to pass checked value to checkbox in Lightning Web Component?

My code looks like:

```js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track isChecked;

    constructor() {
        super();
        isChecked = false;
    }   

}
```

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="My Card" icon-name="custom:custom9">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="my checkbox" name="input1" checked="{isChecked}"></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>    
</template>
```

and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I have figured out how to do this is to add the `checked` attribute using JavaScript.

This example manually adds the `checked` attribute to the DOM element in the setter for `isChecked`.

JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track _isChecked = false;

    set isChecked(newValue) {
        this._isChecked = newValue;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-input.cb').checked = newValue;
    }
    get isChecked() {
        return this._isChecked;
    }

    toggleChecked() {
        this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    }

    onChecboxChange(event) {
        this.isChecked = event.target.checked;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-input class="cb" type="checkbox" label="my checkbox" onchange={onChecboxChange}></lightning-input>
    <br/>
    <lightning-button label="Toggle Checkbox" onclick={toggleChecked}></lightning-button>
    <br/>
    Checked Value: {isChecked}
</template>
```

Example in LWC Playground: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/1wDdErq4X/31/edit

Another way to do this instead of using a setter is to use the `renderedCallback()` lifecycle hook to invoke something like `this.template.querySelector('lightning-input.cb').checked = newValue;` whenever the template renders/re-renders. However, you will need to ensure the variable tracking the checked state is actually bound to the template somewhere, or else the template may not re-render when the variable is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the code I have written for you, it should make sense if not ask me.

Your html for one or more check box

```
<template>
    For multiple Checkbox use Checkbox Group
    <lightning-checkbox-group name="Checkbox Group"
                              label="Checkbox Group"
                              options={options}
                              value={value}
                              onchange={handleChange}></lightning-checkbox-group>
    <p>Selected Values are: {selectedValues}</p>

      for just single Checkbox
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike" id="mycheck" onclick={myFunction}> I have a bike<br>

    <p>Selected:</p> {checkvalue} 
</template>
```

Your js to handle that, For single checkbox right now it assign value (you actuallu asked for ) to check box to keep it simple you can modify it to assign true false depending on last value.

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class CheckboxGroupBasic extends LightningElement {
    @track value = ['option1'];
    @track checkvalue ;

    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'Ross', value: 'option1' },
            { label: 'Rachel', value: 'option2' },
        ];
    }

    get selectedValues() {
        return this.value.join(',');
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.value = e.detail.value;
    }

    myFunction(e){  // it is simple assigning value. here you can toggle value
         this.checkvalue = e.target.value;
    }
}
```

We have LWC Playground link you want to see it working.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/1_UbRgnJ9/9/edit

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
        <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="Hello" icon-name="standard:account">
        <lightning-input type="toggle" label="Name"  onchange={displayStatus} ></lightning-input> 
         <lightning-card>
             {displaytext}
         </lightning-card>
    </lightning-card>   
</template>
=================================js=====================================

import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class ConditionalWebComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track status;
    @track displaytext= '';

    displayStatus(event){
       alert(event.target.checked);
        if(event.target.checked === true){ 
            this.displaytext = 'You are active';
        }if(event.target.checked === false){
            this.displaytext = 'You are inactive';
        }
    }

}
```

event.target.checked - will be used to get value from checkbox

Answer (score 1):

You need to set event on the checkbox in order to track the behavior for example `onclick` and inside on method you can see the value inside `event.target.checked`. Here is sample code:

Checkbox tag:

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" onclick={hereIsTheMethod} label="checkbox" name="someName"></lightning-input>
```

Javascript method:

```
hereIsTheMethod(event){
    console.log(event.target.checked);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, change your code to:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track isChecked;

    constructor() {
        super();
        isChecked = false;
    }   

}
<template>
    <lightning-card title="My Card" icon-name="custom:custom9">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="my checkbox" name="input1" checked={isChecked}></lightning-input>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>    
</template>
```

The checked property needs to be assigned this way:

```
checked={isChecked}
```